# Ruby gem compilation failing on aix 64 bit box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, 64-bit, rubygems, aix

I'm trying to compile ruby 64 bit on aix 64 bit box.
I configured ruby by enabling libpthread. and compiled the same.
But when i try to run ruby setup.rb, i get the following error:

```
/home/xyz/RUBY_64/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.so: load failed -
/home/xyz/RUBY_64/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.so (LoadError)
        from /home/xyz/RUBY_64/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.rb:5
        from /home/xyz/RUBY_64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:85:in
`require'
        from /home/xyz/RUBY_64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:85
        from
/home/xyz/RubyAndRelatedGems/7.3/rubygems-0.9.4/./post-install.rb:81:in
`require'
        from
/home/xyz/RubyAndRelatedGems/7.3/rubygems-0.9.4/./post-install.rb:81:in
`install_sources'
        from
/home/xyz/RubyAndRelatedGems/7.3/rubygems-0.9.4/./post-install.rb:116:in
`run_hook'
        from setup.rb:1526:in `exec_task_traverse'
        from setup.rb:1342:in `exec_install'
        from setup.rb:1000:in `exec_install'
        from setup.rb:814:in `invoke'
        from setup.rb:773:in `invoke'
        from setup.rb:1578
```

I've tried the same with ruby -d option and it does not give any more
information.
Also, ldd on thread.so does not show any dependencies!

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.
I found the reason.
The problem was the way ruby was installed. I reinstalled by disabling libpthread. At this time I got issues in math.c.
I did an explicit expansion of the macros by using -E option and redirecting to a temporary file.
then recompiled using the new file. (I also remember some ruby_thid causing issues. This i rectified by modifying eval.c file)

```
gcc -E -maix64 -O2 -maix64 -fPIC -I/<include dir> -c math.c > /tmp/math.c
mv /tmp/math.c ./math.c
gcc -maix64 -O2 -maix64 -fPIC -I/<include dir> -c math.c
```